# Why float number subtraction in PHP is differ from C

Tags: php, floating-point

C code

```
#include <stdio.h>

union
{
    float f;
    unsigned int u;
} myun;


int main ( void )
{
    float a,b,c;

    a= 4501.490234;
    b= 4501;

    c=a-b;

    myun.f=a; printf("0x%08X %f\n",myun.u,myun.f);
    myun.f=b; printf("0x%08X %f\n",myun.u,myun.f);
    myun.f=c; printf("0x%08X %f\n",myun.u,myun.f);

    return(0);
}
```

The result is:

```
0x458CABEC 4501.490234
0x458CA800 4501.000000
0x3EFB0000 0.490234
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$a = 4501.490234;
$b = 4501;
$c = $a - $b;
echo bin2hex(pack("f", $a))."\n";
echo bin2hex(pack("f", $b))."\n";
echo bin2hex(pack("f", $c))."\n";

$r = unpack('ffloat',"\x00\x00\xFB\x3E");
echo $r['float']."\n";
```

And result:

```
ecab8c45
00a88c45
f3fffa3e
0.490234375
```

So there are two problems.
1. Different subtraction results: f3fffa3e and 0x3EFB0000
2. Even the same 0x3EFB0000 has different representations: 0.490234375 and 0.490234

Comment: Php float precision: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to output number with the same [percision](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.precision)
2. c float uses 4 byte for storing number, php float always uses 8 byte for storing number.

Test your code with double.